# flutter run yields "Timeout reached waiting for exclusive access to file [...]gradle-7.4-all.zip"

Tags: flutter, dart

I received the above error message after trying to run my flutter app on android.
Also cf. [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wZb7.png) of the error.

How can I fix it?
I'm using windows.

Comment: Please make sure to include the error message and all necessary detail in your question as text. Do not simply link to an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message reads "Timeout [...] reached waiting for exclusiv access to file [...]\gradle-7.4-all.zip".

This indicates, the the vscode (or rather the currently running process in the terminal) cannot access the gradle file. Gradle on the other hand is required to build your application for Android.
So - either gradle is not installed on your system or some other process is currently using it. Do you also have another IDE like AndroidStudio running by chance?

I would try the following steps:

- Terminate all other programms and processes that you currently don't need.
- If this does not work, restart your computer
- If this does not work, reinstall gradle

Comment: Thanks it worked after restarting the computer and redownloading ...